# sitecore is failing to publish language versions to web database

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.1

We have upgraded Sitecore to 7.1, but we are experiencing a problem with publishing.

We create a new item in the master database in English, then we publish this item, switch to the web database to check if it's there, which it is, however... The item does not have a version! Therefore the item is not displaying on the website.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the version approved in the final state of workflow?

Comment: Is the template also published to web? you might need to check the logs also.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with Sitecore 8+ where i was able to add language specific content but couldn't publish it. Figured out how to resolve it

1) First Language needs to be registered in \sitecore\system\languages by defining the language to be use.
2) Publish these language items first before publishing content else the behavior will be the same.
3) After publishing languages, then publish the content. In the publish window you will see the language under "Publishing language" section and select the language to publish the content.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that parent items have a version as well and are also in final state if they are part of a workflow.

I had problems with publishing because I didn't have a language version in one of my parents. In my case it was a parent folder under the content node.

Hope it helps.

Al

Comment: the parent items do have a version. after doing a full site publish and getting some further logging info from the Sitecore logs, the log trace says its publishing the item, then it says "Publish operation skippped", the explanation it gives is "Target item could not be found", even though the item has been created (without a version) in the web database...

Comment: See if you have `Publishing.PublishEmptyItems` setting set to `false`. If so, try turning it on.

Answer (score 0):

Please try republishing your entire site. In some cases, a part of the tree hierarchy might be missing in the Web DB, due to which, publishing the child nodes wouldnt  work. Republishing the site can eliminate this chance.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved.

It turns out that the SQL server did not have enough space for a full publish. A full publish had been attempted and failed due to the lack of space on the SQL server. subsequently this had corrupted the database.

We had to restore an earlier version of the database and ensure the SQL server had plenty of space for the full publish to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue earlier with my Sitecore 7.2 upgrade. The key here is to ensure the items, templates and layouts (associated with the item) all has appropriate language+versions in master db. In my case, we were also using Partial Language fallback and needed to make that was working proper as well.

Once you identify the item (with missing versions), add them and republish the whole item. For few template types I noticed Sitecore was still not publishing properly. Ex: Items based off Sublayout Folder template. The fix was easy in this case as I changed the template type to Folder and republished.

Also switch to web database in sitecore client and ensure you are able to preview the item (from web db)

Hope this helps.